# Get an class element's ID

Tags: jquery, razor

I have a group of divs' which belong to the 'userPosts' class and I'm dynamically creating a separate ID for each element. The element I want to animate has the same ID as the button clicked to perform the animation. I want to get the "ID" of all $("textarea") elements with the same ID as the button clicked and animate the textarea with the matching id.

```
@foreach(var post in posts){
        <div id="@post.ID"class="userPosts">
            <button class="view"id="@post.ID">View Post!!!</button><br>
            <h3><strong>Name</strong></h3><br>
            <h5>@post.FirstName</h5><br />
            <h5>@post.LastName</h5><br />
            <h3><strong>Subject</strong></h3><br>
            <h5>@post.Subject</h5><br><br>
            <br><br>
            <textarea id=""rows="4" cols="40">@post.Comments</textarea>
            </div><br><br>

           }
```

This doesn't work but this is what I came up with

```
 $(".view").on("click", function ()
{

    var selected = $(this).attr("id")
    stop().animate(selected, { height: '800px' }, 1000);
    stop().show(selected,"textarea");
    // $(".userPosts").stop().animate({ height: '800px' }, 1000);
    //$(".userPosts textarea").stop().show();
});
```

Comment: Id should be unique. Use data instead (in your case)...

Comment: I still don't get it I think my problem is syntax I got the id of the button but I don't know how to select the textarea with the same id

Comment: C-Link is right. Your div and the button cannot have `id="@post.ID"` All have to be unique.

Comment: Will there only be one textarea for each DIV? So besically you just want to be able to select the textarea that is contained within the div that has the clicked button? If so, there are easy ways to do this. Let me know

Comment: Cory that's exactly what I want to do, can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need ids here - just use classes:
the code below selects the parent DIV (divCont) of the clicked .view button, then uses .find(), to select the textarea with the class .commentsBox. the alert is there just to show that the correct box was selected

see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1com22rh/1/) for a working example:

```
 $(".view").on("click", function () {
  var divCont = $(this).closest("div")
  var txtBox = divCont.find(".commentsBox")
  alert(txtBox.val())

 });
```

once you have selected the correct textarea and give it the var txtBox, you can do whatever you want to to it (like show, animate, fill it--whatever)

keep in mind that this finds the next element with the .commentsBox class in the DIV. If you have more than one .commentsBox element, you would need to use .eq(0) to select the correct one based on index